# How to use tables returned from subquery in SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a  required table like

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|offer_id|Offer_name|Total_offers_sold|total_device_changed|total_offer_changed|
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

now, For first three columns I have found the data using joins and then grouping by offer ID

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|offer_id|Offer_name|Total_offers_sold|
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|12      |abc       |23               |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|23      |gdf       |3                |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|54      |df        |54               |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|56      |gf        |4                |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|65      |ad        |17               |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
|75      |hg        |54               |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

For other two columns i.e. offer_changed and total_device_changed, they are themselves complex queries to find the required data. lets, say I have this sample data found by executing query for those two clumns.

```
+--------+-------------------+
|offer_id|total_offer_changed|
+--------+-------------------+
|12      |3                  |
+--------+-------------------+
|56      |65                 |
+--------+-------------------+
|65      |4                  |
+--------+-------------------+
```

similarly,

```
+--------+--------------------+
|offer_id|total_device_changed|
+--------+--------------------+
|12      |2                   |
+--------+--------------------+
|23      |5                   |
+--------+--------------------+
|75      |20                  |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Now the problem is, these are temporary results and I am unable to understand how to merge the results of this output(tables) in the bigger query corresponding to their offer ID's.i.e the final result I need is :

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|offer_id|Offer_name|Total_offers_sold|total_device_changed|total_offer_changed|
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|12      |abc       |23               |2                   |3                  |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|23      |gdf       |3                |5                   |                   |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|54      |df        |54               |                    |                   |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|56      |gf        |4                |                    |65                 |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|65      |ad        |17               |                    |04                 |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|75      |hg        |54               |20                  |                   |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

please help

Comment: do you want the final table as output in your query?

Comment: Yes!  I wanted the final table as query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT
t1.OFFER_ID,t1.OFFER_NAME,t1.TOTAL_OFFERS_SOLD,
t3.TOTAL_DEVICE_CHANGED,t2.TOTAL_OFFER_CHANGED 
FROM
TABLE1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.OFFER_ID = t2.OFFER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.OFFER_ID = t3.OFFER_ID 
ORDER BY t1.OFFER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are looking for is an inline view. An inline view is a subquery in `from` clause. Unlike subqueries in `select` and `where` clauses, you cannot refer to the other tables in your `from` clause, but you can join the result of the inline query with the tables in your main query.

In your case it would be:

```
select offer_id, offer_name, total_offers_sold
  from table_name t1
       inner join (select offer_id, total_offer_changed
                     from table_name
                    where whatever...
                   ) t2
            on t1.offer_id = t2.offer_id
 where whatever_the_other_conditions
;
```

But, in real world I would simply try to do something like

```
select offer_id, offer_name, total_offers_sold, total_offer_changed
  from table_name
 where whatever_the_conditions
;
```

Read more about inline views on [AskTom.com](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:995030557145) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142293/oracle-inline-view).